# How to force recompile of py source in site-packages?

Tags: python, python-2.7, package

If I edit source of an installed package and delete the .pyc when I restart an app that uses it there is no new pyc generated in place indicating there is a cache elsewhere.

How do I force the update to source to be taken into account?

Comment: Re-compilation should happen automatically. You could force it by deleting the associated `.pyc` files.

Comment: Did you read my query? I already tried that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to the directory of the `.py` file and run `python -m compileall .`.